# Spherical 360 photo coordinates on SCNSphere

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit, panoramas

Best way to explain what I want to do is Google Streets. I have a spherical 360 photo rendered using [CTPanoramaView](https://github.com/scihant/CTPanoramaView) and that works nicely. Now, I need what Google Streets does, a way to detect a tap position on that 360 image and change the image. To do that, I need to somehow "map" coordinates from 2D image to location in 3D sphere. For example, tap on this chandelier bellow opens up another photo (outer space :)

So, disregarding resolution of the photo (or not, pixel resolution can also work, say that photo is 4096 x 2048, I need to convert tap on sphere to tap in that resolution), taking for example that both x and y can go from 0 to 1, I want to detect tap on x=0.247 and y=0.4 on this photo:[image: Photo]

By converting tap from SCNSphere on which this image is rendered to. See this screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

What I currently have is ability to detect tap position in sphere by running [hitTest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522929-hittest) on this [SCNSphere](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnsphere) where photo is rendered and receiving [SCNHitTestResult](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnhittestresult).
SCNHitTestResult seems like a starting point, but I don't really know how to convert it's coordinates to this point I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m not an expert at this, but looking through the docs you provided this method looks promising - `textureCoordinates(withMappingChannel:)`. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Losiowaty I'm soooo glad you pointed this out. This is exactly what returns coordinates I need. Please repost your comment as an answer :)